# Unity Visual Studio activeMQ dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have just joined a company to make some changes to an old project they had. The original team moved on from the project and I just have cloned the repository.

It's a Unity project where they used ActiveMQ for some communication, and VR tools.
When opening the project in unity though, I get the following errors :

[image: errors]

The required DLLs are included in the project hierarchy :

[image: dlls]

I guess I have to get Visual to recognise them, but since I'm quite new to Unity in general I'd like some help :)

The script says this :

[image: script]

Also I can't import the dll in visual studio :

[image: visualimporterror]

Answer (score 0):

Check the script with the namespace **CommunicationShared** and **ActiveMQClient**. I think moving from old version of unity to new will change few things.
Check if the namespace is used right, or get the **updated dll** for new version of unity.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Namespaces.html

Comment: I believe the namespace is correctly used since the project was up and running on their machines. 
I do have a newer version of unity (5.6 instead of 5.4), so I'll check if there are updated dlls

Comment: Also, they're saved as blabla.dll.mdb ; what is that mdb extension and should I remove it ?

Comment: Try that with a backup of your project, you might get some clue doing that.

Comment: edited the question, maybe additionnal info could help ?

Comment: Can you make sure you have selected the correct platform in Build Settings i.e [PC, MAC or Android or IOS] And check the APi Compatibility level in player settings try to set it to .NET 2.0

Comment: I solved the issue, turns out the dlls I was using were either corrupted or empty - I don't really know... but I managed to get a version of the built application, and added the dlls coming with that one and it worked :)

Comment: That's great, It was a .dll issue then.